# Add text to TextBox during ShowDialog and Add_ContentRendered

Tags: wpf, powershell

When loading my PowerShell WPF script, I want some information shown to the user that the script is loading multiple things from Active Directory.
As my script is now, the Window is unresponsive during the loading (which takes aprox 20 seconds), and then when everything is done, the TextBox is updated with the four lines that adds text to the TextBox. I want it to do task 1, update TextBox, then Task 2, update the TextBox and so on. How can I accomplish this?

In the Add_ContentRendered block I have four $WPFlogTxtBox.AddText("Some text"), but these are displayed in the $WPFlogTxtBox all at once when the Add_ContentRendered block is finished, not when they show up in the script.

XAML contains:

```bsh
<TextBox x:Name="logTxtBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="112" Margin="10,290,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="496" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
```

Rest of the script condensed:

```bsh
$Form.Add_ContentRendered({

$WPFlogTxtBox.AddText("Getting OUs")
$OUs = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter '*' | sort Name

$WPFlogTxtBox.AddText("Getting users")
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter * | sort Name

$WPFlogTxtBox.AddText("Getting groups")
$groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter '*' | sort Name

})

$Form.ShowDialog()
```

This works, besides that the text is added to TextBox when everything in Add-ContentRendered is done.

I want the AddText-method to add the text when the command is run, not when the whole invoking block (Add_ContentRendered) is done.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to yield the thread to let the window repaint ...

```
$WPFlogTxtBox.Dispatcher.Yield("ApplicationIdle");
```

A better solution would be to *do the work* on a different thread, and call into the control's dispatcher to update it. [Show-UI](https://github.com/ShowUI) does this sort of thing for you  but you can do it yourself by spinning up another PowerShell runspace -- that's a bit much to get into here. Look at the ShowUI code on github, or at blog posts from [Boe Prox](https://learn-powershell.net/2012/10/14/powershell-and-wpf-writing-data-to-a-ui-from-a-different-runspace/) or [Stephen Owen](https://foxdeploy.com/2016/05/17/part-v-powershell-guis-responsive-apps-with-progress-bars/)

Comment: Great! Will check this out later in the week!